# How to disable next few days from current date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need something like this
(screenshot) http://joxi.ru/UW4IVIwyTJDGAlL7vvM

I've only disabled past days via `minDate: 0`.  How I can get current date and disable next few days (2-3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) options.